# Is it safe to update Linux Xubuntu in a dual boot machine with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot, xubuntu

I have this Samsung notebook with dual boot, running Windows 7 and Xubuntu 12. My main concern is that I use that machine mostly for work, and I don´t want to mess the Windows partition (around 400Gb and full of files I can´t afford losing or recovering). Since Xubuntu software updater keeps telling me that I can upgrade to version 14.04 LTS, I was wondering how far could I go without compromising my entire existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally I've read bad things about Ubuntu's dist-upgrade, there are no shortage of questions on AskUbuntu about failed upgrades. There's also plenty of questions involving clean installs that accidentally erased windows data too.

Whichever method you choose, a **backup** of important data (in linux & windows) is strongly recommended.

The in-Ubuntu upgrade (dist-upgrade) is *supposed* to work well, and it does for many people, and a clean install is *supposed* to go smoothly too, but without a **backup** of important data I wouldn't attempt either, especially on a production working computer.

I'd prefer a clean install.

---

But for now, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is still supported until mid 2017, and if you're happy with the way it works now there's no pressing need to upgrade. Even a few stand-alone programs (like web browsers - they *should* have the latest versions available in the LTS repositories anyway, Office programs, etc) could be updated on their own to the latest versions without needing to update everything - including the kernel - to a whole new Ubuntu version like 14.04 (which is already almost 2 years old) or 16.04 soon.

---

Here's some Q's on AskUbuntu.com I found from a web search for *"ubuntu update stop asking about lts upgrade"*. Looks like a GUI method & a file editing method, *should* do the same thing...?

### [How do I stop Ubuntu from suggesting to upgrade to a non-LTS release?](https://askubuntu.com/a/381322/129271)

1. Open the Dash (By pressing the "Super-Key" / "Windows-Key" / "Ubuntu-Key" / "Command-Key")
2. Search for "Software"
3. Open the application "Software & Updates"
4. Select the "Updates" tab
5. Next to "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" select "None" (or whichever's desired)

### [Disable Ubuntu Update Manager's new version warning](https://askubuntu.com/a/115914/129271)

Either use the GUI method above, or:

Open the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` with your favorite text editor, ie:

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

As in this screenshot from before the change: [image: screenshot]

Change the `Prompt=` line to `Prompt=never`

---

And [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205459/how-do-i-suppress-the-new-release-12-10-available-message) might be useful if the update message keeps appearing, even though it's not supposed to be checking for updates anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I think I will just wait untill it is really necessary :)

Comment: [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com) is taking an "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" approach too, their update manager lists available updates by how "risky" they could be & doesn't recommend updating major components (like the kernel) unless there's a real need to - I like it (Mint's based on Ubuntu, uses their repositories plus their own, currently #1 on http://distrowatch.com I use their XFCE version). And there should be a way to stop the updater from asking you to update to a newer LTS version too, I've added to answer above